# Convert JSON LIST String to JSON Object Flutter FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, serialization

I am making a call to an endpoint that returns a string. How do I format the string to a model, The response is a list of object.

So, within my code, I map the formatted the response to look like

```
//response from server

[
      {
         "name" : "Test Test",
         "age" : 10
      },
      {
         "name" : "Test Test",
         "age" : 10
      }
]

But I formatted it to look as below

Map<String, dynamic> myResponse = {"status": true, "data":  responseFromServer};
```

```
Response model = Response.fromJson(jsonDecode(result));
```

But I get the error as below

```
I/flutter ( 7718): FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)
I/flutter ( 7718): {status: true, data: [{"key":127,"name":"Statement 3!","clientFullName":nul...
I/flutter ( 7718):  ^
```

Here is my model

```
// To parse this JSON data, do
//
//     final response = responseFromJson(jsonString);

import 'dart:convert';

Response responseFromJson(String str) => Response.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String responseToJson(Response data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Response {
    Response({
        this.status,
        this.data,
    });

    bool status;
    List<Datum> data;

    factory Response.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Response(
        status: json["status"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.name,
        this.age,
    });

    String name;
    int age;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        name: json["name"],
        age: json["age"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "age": age,
    };
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to pass the response to a Model and return the model to the used. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

- Please share the code of `CustomModel` to evaluate further.
- Use this [simple tool](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/) to create JSON to dart class in and integrate in seconds.

Comment: I have updated the question,its supposed to be Response not CustomModel